# Export image sequence by moving layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I want to export a simple animation for a rolling background. I need to move one layer to the left x pixels, then export as "frame*.png" and repeat. (Where * is the number of the frame. I need to repeat this like y times. I tried to work with actions but I can't export with different names and don't know how to repeat actions. I found the Animation Timeline in CC2015 but I think it doesn't fit my need, does it?

Comment: [Create a Droplet](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html#create_a_droplet_from_an_action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timeline to create the animation.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-timeline-animations.html

For the sake of simplicity let's say you want to have an animation with 10 frames, moving your layer 10 pixels to the right between images (so your layer will travel 100 pixels in total).

- Open the timeline (Window > Timeline) and click "Create Frame
  Animation".
- under the timeline, click on the button "Duplicates selected frames".
- The newly created frame will be selected. Move your layer to the
  position it will be in the last image (100 pixels to the right) using
  the arrow keys or the mouse.
- Now select both frames in the Timeline window (shift+click).
- Click on "Tweens animation frames". Select how many frames to add (in
  this example, 10 frames). Select the parameter "Position" and hit
  OK.
- Now you just need to export your animation. Go to "File > Export >
  Render Video" and select "Photoshop Image Sequence". Then you can
  select PNG as file format and change the name of the files.
- Hit Render and check the result.

Comment: excellent answer. Exactly what I was looking for